# Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am a beginner and facing error on installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package. Error Package Restore Failed

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your Android project is not targeting the latest Android Framework. You can check it under the project properties.

[image]